# how to round decimal value to next quarter

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, rounding

Any way to round up decimal value to its next quarter (0.25,0.50,0.75) in C#.Net?
I am getting wrong rounding with Math.Floor function

**Example:**

```
5.125 -> 5.25
6.390 -> 6.50
7.610 -> 7.75
8.950 -> 9.00 

decimal UltimateRounding(decimal amountToRound, decimal nearstOf, decimal 
fairness, decimal final)
{
    return Math.Floor(amountToRound / nearstOf + fairness + final) * nearstOf;
}
```

Comment: I removed your asp.net tag.  Please don't use irrelevant tags.  People who don't know asp.net might ignore this question even though it has nothing to do with asp.net.

Comment: Please post the results of your function / formula

Comment: Is this always rounding up as your example indicates, or would you round down if it was closer?

Comment: Also, need to know what numbers you are trying to plug in to:  nearstOf + fairness + final -- I don't know why you would need all that if you are just rounding to the next quarter.

Comment: Fortunately those values are exactly representible as a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var a = 5.125m;
a = Math.Ceiling(a * 4) / 4;
```